# magnific-popup миниатюра

Tags: html, jquery, css

как изменить размер миниатюры в magnific-popup?
в документации не нашел, при изменении в стилях с 75*75 до 150*150 миниатюра просто растягивается

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, в этом примере миниатюра и изображение — это 2-ва разных изображения.